# can a MDM send alerts and sound notifications in iOS?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, mdm

I have a MDM server with APNSWrapper Python that is able to send commands and receive response from the iOS device.
However all this happens in background and is not perceivable to user.
Is there any command that MDM server can use to send text-alerts or sounds or badges like app based notifications work?
Any help would be appreciable.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing in the MDM protocol that allows the MDM server to send text-alerts, sounds, or badges to the user. You would need to create an application to do that.